# Node.js: require() and passing variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Started a project with npm which created a certain file structure:

> www <-- require() calls app.js; instantiates server
>
> app.js <-- instantiates var app = express(); and has module.exports = app;

Now, I'd like to use sockets.io. In my 'www' file, here is a code snippet:

`var app = require('../app');
...
var server = http.createServer(app);`

And I'd like to put all of my server-side socket listeners in app.js, but the following code:

`var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);`

requires server as an input. How do I make the server I instantiated in 'www' accessible in 'app.js'?

Comment: What's the entry point of your app? It seems to be `www` so why not put your `var io` in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a little strange. But if you insist on such a structure than you can export an object from `www` that will have `app` as it's property and a method that binds socket listeners an receives `app` object as a param.

```
module.exports = {
    app:  app,
    bindSocketListeners: function(server, io) {
        io.listen(server);
        return io; 
    } 
};
```

And call it:

```
var appObj = require('../app');
var io = require('socket.io');
var app = appObj.app;
var server = http.createServer(app);
io  = appObj.bindSocketListeners(server, io)
```

Comment: Thanks, helpful. Why would you say that's strange? Unless I want a million listeners for my whole app in my www file, it would make more sense to have only the socket listeners for each served page in those respective pages, at which point I have to pass that same io variable around, which has to bind to the same server. What would common practice be?

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems for me to more logic to have in a common file for application handling and server creation and another for app configuration (for setting middlewares,  routes, sockets etc.). Nevertheless you are your application's boss and you decide! :) Cheers!